# How can I read data bytes in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ipad

I want to make an `image` file from trough all iPad internal disk from byte 0 to end..

How can I read it from objective c?

Comment: You can't. Apple won't allow it.

Comment: @AMADANON Inc, really!! i want to develop recovery data application, and i need to read bytes... i saw that somebody made it in http://www.transfer-iphone-recovery.com/recover-deleted-files-from-ipad.html .. but i need detect my own deleted files..

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw "in IOS" and thought you were referring to an app (which Apple won't allow). If you follow the instructions on the site you mentioned, you should get your ipad to show up as a USB disk. In that case, what platform are you developing on? Windows? Linux? Mac? This makes a difference.

Comment: @AMADANON Inc,tanx, wow i didnt know that apple don`t allow to this app.. but i download it in my mac and i changed my ipad to DFU mode and then i run it and my images recovered.. i can jailbreak my ipad if i can access to my custom files that i saved it in my ipad and then deleted by bad child..

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh totally different scope, you can potentially read every bit from an attached USB device to a Mac or a PC, but you may not from an app hosted on a running iOS device.  There are actually big problems preventing you from doing block level backup from a running OS of any sort... I don't want to say it can't be done because there are probably RTOS's designed for the purpose, but in general you can't

Comment: @Grady Player, tanQ.. then is there a way for reading data if i attach it to pc or mac with usb? in DFU mode or ..? can you refer me to site or library or ..? i worked with c# and objective c and i know about reading bytes from attached disk but in DFU mode not windows and not mac, didn`t attach any disks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now that I have enough information...

You can't do this as an app on the ipad. You can do this by hooking your ipad to a computer (mac, windows, linux). You mentioned mac, so I will give the instructions for that.

You will need to have administrator privileges on your mac. Follow the instructions at the link, to get your ipad to show up as a drive.

Open a shell window. Type in `mount`. Look through the items listed for a line that starts with /dev/ - there may be several. Find the one that is your ipad. If you are not sure, unplug the ipad, run `mount` again, and see which one disappears (re-plug after). This represents the filesystem on your ipad. You should be able to read it with a program of your choosing - just treat it as a file. Be *VERY* careful what changes you make - it wouldn't take much to trash your ipad. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!

You may still not be able to access all files on your ipad - there may be other partitions, which are not available over USB.

Comment: tanx alot, its better answer than noah upvote and accepted. and another questions, did you know about reading or writing access in DFU mode? what privileges we have in DFU mode?

Comment: I think you should have read and write access, so long as you have administrator privileges in OSX. I don't use OSX, so I'm not exactly sure how you get them - probably `sudo` or `su` (google is your friend).

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not possible with an iOS app on a non-jailbroken device. Third-party apps are sandboxed and can only read data from a specific area of the filesystem.

Comment: tanx, i got it .. then i only should used unallowed jobs using jailbreak to recover my custom files..! is it true? and making disk image?